# how we can use evaluateAsync in phantomjs

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

what's the usage of `evaluateAsync` and when we have to use this function and what's the benefit of using this function .
in the below we see a poor [documentation](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate-async.html) for this :

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();
// @TODO: Finish page.evaluateJavaScript example.
```

any body can show a example of usage of `evaluateAsync` in phantomjs

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This function allows you to execute any JavaScript code like the `evaluate` API function.
But it will evaluate your code asynchronous. It means:

- Current execution context will not be blocked.
- It will not return any result.

Let's say you want execute some long-running JavaScript code, but you don't interested in its result. If you will use `evaluate`, your current execution context will be blocked.

The documentation for `evaluateAsync` is a bit wrong. The correct signature for `evaluateAsync` is:
`evaluateAsync(function, ms, args)`, where:

- function - the function to evaluate
- ms - time to wait before execution
- args - function arguments

**Example:**

```
evaluateAsync(function() {
   console.log('Hi! I\'m evaluateAsync call!');
}, 1000);
```

**Using in the real world:**

- You want to capture some asynchronous events.
- Unit testing! AFAIK, PhantomJS runners use `evaluateAsync` to run unit tests.

Comment: i want get a string from document dom every 1 sec and send it's answer to other function... what is better for me ? evaluateAsync or evaluate

Comment: You'd better use `evaluate` with `setInterval`, something like this:
`setInterval(function() { myText = page.evaluate(function() { return dom.text; } )});`

Comment: id do that .. but after 20min phantomjs crash and show below error :
PhantomJS has crashed. Please read the crash reporting guide at...

Comment: If you see a crash, follow this guide about crash reporting: http://phantomjs.org/crash-reporting.html
And we'll take a look into this.

Comment: The documentation should really be fixed...the only reason I got my code working is because I stumbled upon this SO post.